# SAS EG casting sting to date getting different results on different machines - or where is SAS locale setting?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Have string `"09/07/2019 20:40:01 EDT"`

Run command in SAS EG 7.1 connecting to a remote UNIX server

```
input(substr(event_time, 1, length(event_time)-4),anydtdtm23.) format DateTime23.3 as event_time
```

One machine comes back correctly as Sep 07, 2019.  (dropping the time bit for clarity)
The other machine  comes back as July 09, 2019.

Based on what I've read in related questions it seems to be caused by locale setting

What governs SAS locale setting ? Is it my OS  ? the Remote UNIX server ? Something in SAS EG settings ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you fix the original strings to use a style that is unambiguous?

Comment: No, strings are coming from a source I don't control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a guessing procedure unless you must. The ANYDT... series of informats will assume that ambiguous MDY or DMY stings follow the custom of the current language settings of your SAS session.  So if SAS thinks you are in England then '09/07/2019' looks like the 9th of July.  But if you are in the US then it looks like September 7th.

Instead read the string using either the MMDDYY or DDMMYY informat, depending on what format the strings are actually stored in.  If your source actually is using  mixed month day ordering styles then write code that uses information from your data to pick the right informat for a particular observation instead of forcing SAS to use your session setting to decide which one to use.

Comment: Yeah, using MDYAMPM  avoids the problem. I was curious what governs the guess work behind anydtdtm, and if there is any way to influence that process.

Comment: Check the EG documentation. I believe the default for EG and Studio are to configure the SAS session to match the setting of the machine that is connecting. So you can have one SAS server that is used by people with different preferences.